# How to index: in C?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main() {

    char a[] = "1234:once:echo hello";
    int i = 0;
    while(i < strlen(a)) {
       if(a[i] == ':') {
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    a = a + i;
    printf("%s\n", a);
}
```

This program just iterates through string a until it hits ':', then I want to a to become ":once:echo hello" which I tried doing by adding i. Not sure why it isn't working I remember something similar work in the past.

Comment: You can't increment array in C.

Comment: Arrays are _not_ pointers.  You can't modify an array by `a = a + i;`, though you can do that with a pointer.  So, you'll need a pointer variable and you can initialize, modify and print that.

Comment: Read the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you simply want to walk through your text and locate the first `':'` and then print the remainder of `a` from that point until the end, you can do it quite easily with the index generated by your loop, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void) {

    char a[] = "1234:once:echo hello";
    int i = 0;

    while (a[i]) {          /* loop over each char */
    if (a[i] == ':')     /* 1st semi-colon found */
            break;          /* exit loop */
        i++;                /* increment index */
    }
    printf ("%s\n", a + i); /* output string from index */
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/walkarray
:once:echo hello
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues with your example code. First you are not incrementing the value of `i` inside the while loop which is creating an infinite loop.  As Jonathan has suggested in the comments you'd be better off using a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop.

Secondly, you can't increment an array in C. When I try to compile your example using `clang` I get `error: array type 'char [21]' is not assignable`

You can achieve your goal by doing the pointer arithmetic in the `printf` statement rather than trying to save the new value back into `a`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char a[] = "1234:once:echo hello";
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(a); i++) {
       if(a[i] == ':') {
            break;
        }
    }

    printf("%s\n", a + i);
}
```

Comment: If you're going to use a loop, that cries out for a `for` loop rather than a `while` loop.  And it is best not to use `strlen(a)` in the condition like that; it might be evaluated on each iteration, leading to quadratic performance.  The print could simply be `printf("%s\n", &a[i]);`, could it not?  Or `a + i` instead of `&a[i]`.

Comment: Good points! I was just fixing the initial issue. Will up date with your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 0;
while ( a[i] && a[i] != ":") i++; // loop ends when a[i] is NULL or a[i] is ":"
char *b = &a[i];
printf("%s", b);
```